# Determine the value of x that will allow the maximum amount of light that can enter that window if its perimeter is 20 ft.

Tags: calculus, optimization

[Diagram](https://i.stack.imgur.com/0MUai.png)

I am having trouble finding the perimeter and area functions using only two variables.

Comment: Call the diagonal edge $z$. Then $x + 2y + 2z = 20$, so $z = \frac{x + 2y - 20}{2}$. Now an expression for the area in terms of $x,y,z$ can be converted to an expression in terms of just $x$ and $y$.

Comment: what is the proper area formula??

Comment: Also what are the steps to solving the actual problem??

Comment: @JohnHughes according to your consideration, $\ f(z) =f(x,y)$ won't have any critical point. I think there is some condition missing.

Comment: @PortalSSS is this window has to be considered as a 3-d figure?

Comment: No, it is just a normal 2d window. I just don't know how to find a value of x that allows the maximum amount of light to go through said window.

Comment: Of course, there are other constraints, like $x \ge 0$ and $x \le 20$. And if we write $u = x/2$, then evidently $z^2 - u^2 = h^2$, where $h$ is the height of the triangular portion, allowing us to write $A = xy + \frac{xh}{2}$...

Comment: I’ve found that but I don’t know how to find just a singular x.

Comment: For any fixed $x$, can you figure out the minimum and maximum allowable values of $y$? If so, then you can maximize (in $y$). Now for each $x$, you have a maximum, and you can maximize over **those**.

Comment: I cannot find a formula that gives me only a one variable.